# Don't Dim Main Content When DrawerLayout Is Visible?

Tags: android, drawerlayout

When using a [DrawerLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html) in Android, opening a drawer causes the main content area to be darkened.  Is there any way to avoid this so the main content stays equally visible while the drawer is out?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try using `drawerLayout.setScrimColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);`

Comment: That's exactly it, thanks!  I searched for "dim", "darken", "transp", etc.  ???scrim???

Comment: For the curious who have never heard of "scrim" before: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrim_(material)